# Error occurred during initialization of VM;Unable to load native library:Can't find dependent libraries

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I used JNI to call java.I copied the jvm.dll to the directory of myprogram.exe,but When I ran it shown as above.I did as other answer:try adding C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_14\jre\bin\client to the PATH,it's Ok. 
But I exc the cmd dumpbin /dependents jvm.dll,it only showed Windows system dll.
So I want to know if the  jvm.dll needs other depends?

Answer (score 1):

In my own poking around using "[Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)" jvm.dll run-time loads VERIFY.DLL, JAVA.DLL and ZIP.DLL. The trick is they need to be 2 directories above and in a bin sub-directory (just like the layout in the JRE layout)

[image]

Comment: it did as you said